# Create linear predictions with Stata

Tags: regression, linear-regression, stata, predict

I want to run a regression of profits against time and see whether there is a change in the last 6 months. To do so, I want to have the regression before July and then get estimates for the whole year assessing whether there is a difference from the actual values.

I use:

```
areg profits date if date<td(30,6,2021), a(company) vce(cluster date)
predict profits_reg
```

However, the predictions are only generated for the first 6 months, I don't get the predictions for the days from July 1st, the cells are empty (.)

How can I ensure that I get predictions for all data in my data set?

Comment: I can't see your dataset, but neither do I get this problem with an attempt to mimic the procedure.

Comment: Needs a minimal reproducible example.